# how to use while loop with more than one argument?

Tags: delphi

I want make a countdown timer in Delphi. I used

```
while(t<>0 and m<>0 and s<>0) do
```

but the program doesn't accept it. How can I fix this?

Comment: It should be while (t<>0) and (m<>0) and (s<>0) do.

Comment: Just one note; this won't work as a main loop for a countdown timer (if that is the intention; I'm not sure, since I would expect variables `h`, `m`, `s`, not `t`, `m`, `s`, but that might come from your native language and I assume `t` to be an hour variable). If that is so, consider what happens when you'll start counting, say on 10 seconds. You will have `h=0, m=0, s=10`, and you try to count down only when `(h <> 0) and (m <> 0) and (s <> 0)` which won't pass even single iteration because `h` and `m` variables are already in 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer, very appreciate. i used it and it works, but i have the sam problem that the loop goes very very fast and it shows the final time, 0:0:0. and it doesn't show coutdown secondly... i need your help to solve this problem and for thi i add the program, thanks

Comment: procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject) begin  while (t<>0) or (m<>0) or (s<>0) do   begin Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(t)+':'+IntToStr(m)+':'+IntToStr(s); for i:=0 to 59 do  begin ms:=ms+1; if s<>0 then  begin  dec(s);  endelse begin if m=0 then begin  if t=0 then  Label2.Caption:='it is done' else   begin dec(t); m:=59; s:=60;  end; end else begin dec(m); s:=60; Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(t)+':'+IntToStr(m)+':'+IntToStr(s) ;

Comment: i'm sorry that i couldn't attach the program and i had to delete a lot to send you this.. hope that you can see it. thanks.

Comment: my problem is to show at screen countdown each second as a timer. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

The code you need is:

```
while (t<>0) and (m<>0) and (s<>0) do
```

The reason is that Pascal precedence rules mean that in your code, `and` attempts to bind as a bitwise operator to the integers around it. The parens above are needed to make `and` operate here as a logical operator.

Your expression is

```
t<>0 and m<>0 and s<>0
```

Because `and` has a higher precedence than `<>`, then the expression is interpreted as:

```
t<>(0 and m)<>(0 and s)<>0
```

which is a clear syntax error.

Precedence is documented here:

[Expressions (Delphi) | Operator Precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops at all inside your function. This is because you are working from the timer which calls once per time interval.

You simply need to decrement the variables like this

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject) 
begin 
  Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(t)+':'+IntToStr(m)+':'+IntToStr(s); 
  if s > 0 then dec( s)
  else
  begin
    s := 59;
    if m>0 then dec(m)
    else
    begin
      m := 59;
      if t>0 then dec( t )
      else Label2.Caption:='it is done' 
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this... i has appeard another problem with theTimer... when i restart the process the old value of timer appears and count it down... i used a button to terminate the whole application, but it doesn't worked. i switched off the computer and restart again and compile the program with other values, but the timer conitnues with the old time... i don't know how should i reset the timer? because there is not such a command... i appreciate your kindly help... best regards, venus

Comment: You need to say where you get your initial timer values (t, m and s) from. It is unusual for them to persist - or are you saying that they don't persist and you want them to?

Comment: thanks for your respond...i used an example and the countdown worked very good. and i closed the program before the countdown was finished. and when i run the original program, it appeared the old time and continued with countdown.  i actually calculate something and the process needs special time which should be countdown to fullfill the process. i put a button to stop or finish it by using Application.Terminate, but it doesn't work. i added Timer1.Enabled:=false; and it almost work. and in previous procedure i added Timer1.Enabled:=true; and it work.. i need better solution regards, venus

Comment: OK I think that I understand. This is really another question so you should mark this one as complete and start a new one. However, what you need to do is in your Form.OnClose store the current time (Now()) and the values of t, m and s somewhere, eg. in the Registry or an INI file, then read those values back in order to recalculate t, m and s with the new values. If you need more help than this, please start a new thread.